# "PanicException: no entry found for key" error running simpletransformers on Google Colab

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, simpletransformers

I encountered this error while running simpletransformers on Google Colab. I enabled h/w accelerator as GPU and ran the code.

```
from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel


# Create a ClassificationModel
model = ClassificationModel("bert", "sagorsarker/bangla-bert-base",num_labels=2, use_cuda=True, args={
    'reprocess_input_data': True,
    'use_cached_eval_features': False,
    'overwrite_output_dir': True,
    'num_train_epochs': 3,
    'silent': True
})

# Train the model
model.train_model(train)
```

Full Error -

```
Some weights of the model checkpoint at sagorsarker/bangla-bert-base were not used when initializing BertForSequenceClassification: ['cls.predictions.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.bias', 'cls.predictions.decoder.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.bias']
- This IS expected if you are initializing BertForSequenceClassification from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing BertForSequenceClassification from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
Some weights of BertForSequenceClassification were not initialized from the model checkpoint at sagorsarker/bangla-bert-base and are newly initialized: ['classifier.weight', 'classifier.bias']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/simpletransformers/classification/classification_model.py:449: UserWarning: Dataframe headers not specified. Falling back to using column 0 as text and column 1 as labels.
  "Dataframe headers not specified. Falling back to using column 0 as text and column 1 as labels."
Exception in thread Thread-13:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 431, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: no entry found for key
```

And it freezes at this moment. Nothing happens despite the cell running. What should I do to make it work?

Edit:

I solved it for the time being using simpletransformers version 0.50.0

Comment: I installed an older version of simpletransformers and it's working alright

Comment: Was the error you got been solved?

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma no,  I made it work with version 0.50.0

Comment: but i am using the huggingface/transformers. So any information about the version of it?

Comment: And another concern about the `sagorsarker/bangla-bert-base` version

Comment: I'm sorry, not sure about the version

Comment: I also made an issue to simpletransformers about it but got no response, [simpletransformers- pyo3_runtime.PanicException](https://github.com/ThilinaRajapakse/simpletransformers/issues/1091)